# Qt, C++: QListWidget internal drag&drop - how to connect to signal?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I write in C++ using Qt, and I have a list widget.

I enabled internal drag & drop, using:

```
list->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

What should I do for catching the signal that says that such a drag & drop action was done?

Thanks!

Comment: You can start by reading the Qt documentation on Drag and Drop: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just assuming this is the sort of signals your looking for...

`myList->model()->rowsMoved()` or `myList->model()->layoutChanged`

Links to docs:

[`QAbstractItemModel::rowsMoved`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved)

[`QAbstractItemModel::layoutChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged)

Example:

```
connect(list->model(), SIGNAL(rowsMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex,int)), this, SLOT(myFunction()));
```

Comment: @user3322273 cgood point worth having an example to copy from i guess, mark as answered?

Comment: this connection on "rowsMoved" never works for me, never into slot